# Spring MVC - do not create session for request

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, request, httprequest

is it possible to tell Spring MVC to not create a session for certain request?

We have application running in Spring MVC, we have many controller methods like these:
/add_client 
/show_order 
... etc

it is obvious the we need a session for these methods, 
but we have also one special request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/monitoring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String monitoring(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // do some check
    return "monitoring";
}
```

for monitoring requests we don't want to create a session.

If I am googling or searching here, all that I found was: "I want a session but it isn't created or doesn't work properly" but I want to fix this: "I have a session but I don't want it (for certain request)"

Is there some option in Spring MVC to achieve this?

Ladislav

Comment: Could it be that the model parameter is initializing the session?

Comment: I have removed Model parameter, but session was created in this case too, I have DefaultSessionListener configured for notification about session beeing created, I have modified example sourcecode (Model was removed)

Answer (score 0):

Create hidden variable   in .jsp file for request that you don't want to keep session.
In your controller method check

```
public String yourMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Your model, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelmap) {

           if( model.isHiddenPath() ){ // you dont want to keep session 
            request.getSession(false);
}
else{
request.getSession(true);
```

It would be hard to check for all yours methods in controller.It would be better to use interceptor .

Comment: request.getSession(false) returns NULL if session was not created yet (passing true means session will be created if it wasn't yet), but in my case the session was created already, so this method just returns Session object,